# General solution of $tx''-x'+4t^3x=4t^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The task is to find general solution of:

$tx''-x'+4t^3x=4t^3$

The hint is to substitute $s=t^2$

**My attempt:** First I guessed that $x=1$ satisfies the equation and that is our particular solution. Now we have to find the solution to homogeneous eqaution:

$tx''-x'+4t^3x=0$

My quess was to use $x=\exp{(at^2)}$ and after  plugging it into equation we get that a=+/- i so our solutions would be $\cos (t^2)$ and $\sin (t^2)$

So the finall answer is that general solution is $x(t)= C_1 \cos (t^2) + C_2 \sin (t^2) +1 $

But the problem is that I didn't use the hint in any part of it and I don't think that's the right way to solve this problem. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute $s = t^2$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{ds}.(2t)$$

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 4t^2\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + 2\frac{dx}{ds}$$

Now, substituting those into our original DE

$$4t^3\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + 2t\frac{dx}{ds} - 2t\frac{dx}{ds} + 4t^3x = 4t^3$$

$$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + x  = 1$$

The simplification basically transforms this into a linear DE which can be easily factorised and solved

Comment: I solved this up to the point where $x(s) = c_1 \cos{s}+c_2\sin{s}+1$. Is my solution then $x(t^2) = c_1 \cos{t^2}+c_2\sin{t^2}+1$?

Comment: Yes. and that's what you get when you do it the other way also